# how find file name in a server source using php

Tags: php, html, pdf, web-scraping

i have a link.when clicking on that link a pdf file will be downloaded. am trying to save that file to a folder. with static name it getting saved,but i want to save with its actual name,is that possible? if anybody knows please help me.

sample url:- http://www.intercoat.de/index.php?option=com_jdownloads&Itemid=206&task=finish&cid=341&catid=178&lang=en

am  attaching my code below. i have an array of links like above sample link
so am fetching it from an array

```
foreach($li as $lm)
  {        
    $i++;          
    $file_info = new finfo(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
    $mime_type = $file_info->buffer(file_get_contents($lm));

    if($mime_type=='application/pdf')
    {
      echo $lm.$i.'<br>';
      $filecontent = file_get_contents($lm);
      file_put_contents('./uploads/myfile'.$i.'.pdf', $filecontent);
    }   

  }
```

now all files not saving with its exact name,it saves as myfile1,myfile2 ..etc
cant take base name because the file name is not in url.that urls are just source of file. anybody knows please help

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
foreach($li as $lm)
{
    $i++;

    $file_info = new finfo(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
    $mime_type = $file_info->buffer(file_get_contents($lm));

    if($mime_type=='application/pdf')
    {

        echo $lm.$i.'<br>';
        $filecontent = file_get_contents($lm);
        $actual_name = basename($lm); 
        file_put_contents('./uploads/'.$actual_name', $filecontent);

     }
}
```

Comment: we cant use basename of,it fetches base name of url only

Comment: what did you get in $lm?

Comment: did you see that above url. urls like that getting in $lm. in that location we get file.but file name not present in url